# Problem with app on flutter after build apk

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have written an application that can give information about an IP address. I receive data from the API in json format and when I click on the get info button, I check if the input field is empty and if the IP is correct. As a result, the data is displayed on the screen, but here's the problem. After building the application in the apk, when you click on the button, nothing happens, while in debug mode everything works. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

In the application, I used an API called ip-api

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

var country = "Country: ";
var city = "City: ";
var timezone = "Timezone: ";
var operator = "Operator: ";
var latitude = "Latitude: ";
var longitude = "Longitude: ";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

TextEditingController ipController = new TextEditingController();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tracksploit',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Tracksploit'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              "IP Adress", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 35
              )
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 30),

            TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              controller: ipController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Any IP Adress'
              )
            ),
            
            const SizedBox(height: 15),

            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),

              child: const Text('Get Info'),
              onPressed: () async {
                Response data = await get(Uri.parse("http://ip-api.com/json/" + ipController.text));
                Map jsonData = jsonDecode(data.body);

                if (ipController.text == ""){
                  _displayDialog2(context);
                } else {
                  if (jsonData['status'] == 'fail') {
                    _displayDialog(context);
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      country = "Country: " + jsonData['country'];
                      city = "City: " + jsonData['city'];
                      operator = "Operator: " + jsonData['isp'];
                      timezone = "Timezone: " + jsonData['timezone'];
                      latitude = "Latitude: " + jsonData['lat'].toString();
                      longitude = "Longitude: " + jsonData['lon'].toString();
                    });
                  }
                }
              }
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            const Divider(
              thickness: 5
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),

            Text(
              "$country", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text(
              "$city", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text(
              "$timezone", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text(
              "$operator", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text(
              "$latitude", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text(
              "$longitude", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

void _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Expanded(
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text('Invalid IP Adress!'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
}

void _displayDialog2(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Expanded(
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text('Type any IP Adress please!'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple,),
              ),)
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly check this permission is there in android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```